# Ruby on rails, deactivation of a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am using sorcery gem for user authentication.
My model is:

```
 create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                                          :null => false
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                     :null => false
    t.string   "remember_me_token"
    t.datetime "remember_me_token_expires_at"
    t.string   "activation_state"
    t.string   "activation_token"
    t.datetime "activation_token_expires_at"
 end
```

I could not find in the internet if there is a built-in function for deactivating a user. Will it be safe to find a user and just change the parameter `activation_state` to inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

`user.setup_activation`

it will set `activation_state` to 'pending' and create new `activation_token`.

Or you can set `activation_state` to 'pending' manually. That's all.